# Unable to create a FK constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables:

```
TableA
------
TableAID INT IDENTITY Primary Key
TableBID INT NULL

I add a unique constraint on TableBID
ALTER TABLE TableAID ADD CONSTRAINT xx UNIQUE ([TableBID])

TableB
------
TableBID INT IDENTITY Primary Key
```

Now when I delete TableA row, I need TableB's to be deleted as well, so i am trying to add a FK with cascade delete

```
ALTER TABLE TableB ADD CONSTRAINT yy FOREIGN KEY (TableBID) 
REFERENCES TableA (TABLEBID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But I get this error:

```
Msg 1788, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
Cascading foreign key 'yy' cannot be created where the referencing column 'TableB.TableBID' is an identity column.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TableB.TableBID cannot simultaneously be an IDENTITY column (which is calcluated independently) and at the same time be a foreign key from a column in another table.

I think you've got your relationship reversed and actually want:

```
ALTER TABLE TableA ADD CONSTRAINT yy FOREIGN KEY (TableBID) 
REFERENCES TableB (TABLEBID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: When I switched the tables the error went away, but shouldn't I be adding the constraint on TableB as I want the TableB row to be deleted when TableA row is deleted.

Comment: It sounds like you'd want to reverse everything then. TableB should have a column that references TableA's PK as a foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

> Now when I delete TableA row, I need TableB's to be deleted as well, so i am trying to add a FK with cascade delete

This scenario requires you to create the relationship the other way.
Otherwise, create a trigger in A that will remove the matching record in B when A is deleted.

> When I switched the tables the error went away, but shouldn't I be adding the constraint on TableB as I want the TableB row to be deleted when TableA row is deleted.

An FK implies that the master is B and one or more records in A links to it (in your case, you have restricted it to one-to-one using the unique key). Cascade delete removes the child part of the FK when the master is removed, so delete B -> removes matching A, not the other way around.  You need a trigger for this.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the identity specification under table design..then it worked